# How to automate updates to Elasticsearch indexes when using Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I created two Docker containers. One based on Elasticsearch and one based on Logstash. The only thing I change about the containers is that I include the config files. I have them automatically built when pushing to git.

I would like to automate the deployment, however, I can't because whenever a change is made to a template, the indexes need to be recreated.

I have Logstash set to manage the Elasticsearch templates. The .conf file has this output config:

```
output {
    elasticsearch {
      hosts => ["${LOGSTASH_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST}"]
      index => "posts"
      ilm_enabled => false
      document_id => "%{id}"
      doc_as_upsert => true
      manage_template => true
      template => "/usr/share/logstash/mysql/posts.template.json"
      template_name => "posts.template"
      template_overwrite => true
    }
}
```

However, this does not update data that is already saved in Elasicsearch. How would I automate the process of updating the template and reindexing so that I can roll out changes automatically?

Answer (score 0):

you'd need to write your own script for this, it's not something that the Elastic Stack currently has functionality to detect and manage for you sorry to say

Comment: Do you know of any documentation or tutorials to do something like this? I've had a hard time finding any.

Comment: not directly. it'd be a script that you would need to call after the config update that calls the reindex api, but given you have all the data in a single index it's a little more complex